# Looking for a way to mimic the battery-saving behavior of closing the lid without actually doing so

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, battery, hibernate

I'm looking for a way to keep the lid up, yet tell my Macbook Pro Late 2013 to do what it would do if the lid was actually closed. When I close the lid, the battery lasts for a long time, not so when the lid is open but I sleep the display.

I would like a way to tell my Macbook to sleep the display, yet if no interaction after a certain amount of time, then go into the mode comparable to closing the lid. All while keeping the lid open at all times because I have an external display and it's unnecessary having to close the lid when I'm done using it. When I'm ready to use it, I would just wake it using my bluetooth keyboard, or the power button. That would be comparable to opening the lid.

I have my hibernation setting at 3.

I'm sure there are some terminal commands to make this happen, I'm just unaware of it.

Comment: Put a magnet on the edge of the case to simulate the lit closing. Almost as real as it gets.

Comment: How did you set your hibernation setting?

Comment: @DavidVincent here's the post about it http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127650/131205

Answer (score 1):

You can find these options in System Preferences > Energy Saver.

Drag the "Computer Sleep:" slider to the left.

[image: Energy Saver Preferences]

Note that for newer Apple portables, Yosemite combines the sleep and display sleep option:

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2013-mba-no-computer-sleep-setting-wtf-heres-why.1598329/

Comment: I am using Yosemite and I don't see the computer sleep option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with time you can do like Ender says, or simply do it directly by clicking on the Apple on the top-left corner and click Suspend Activity (Go in sleeping mode)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Ctrl + Shift + Eject`, this puts the mac to sleep.  On a Macbook you need to use `Ctrl + Shift + Power` since there is no eject button (unless you are using an external keyboard).