# Macbook pro 13 inch 2017 W/ touch bar - battery drain during sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, high-sierra

OS Version I'm on is High Sierra 10.13.2

My battery seems to drain way too much on my new MacBook Pro 13 w/ Touch bar 2017 when it's supposed to be sleeping.  Things I've done after reading other posts on the issue:

- Turned off power nap on battery in the settings
- Turned on Do Not Disturb whilst sleeping

After a test yesterday, at the end of a day the battery went from 100% to 84%, I didn't open the lid once in that time.

I don't recall ever having this issue with my MacBook Air mid 2012.

Is this a software, hardware issue or both?

Thanks

**UPDATE 01/01/2018 -** Happy new year! So I did as suggested in reply.  Nothing was open preventing sleep.  20hrs this time on sleep and down to 78%.  This can't be right!

Comment: The more RAM is used the more battery drain there is.

Comment: Yes as RAM requires power. I'm not keeping any more applications open than I used to though. Usage is the same.

Comment: Did you find any solution? It's ridiculous! Yesterday I let my 2017 15" mbp go to sleep as usual (auto sleep after 15 mins) with 58% battery. After 8-9 hours, in the evening, when I woke it up, it had 3% battery left! Insane! At the same time my late 2013 13 inch mbpr barely lost 2% during the same time!

Comment: Bluetooth definitely makes a difference. I never used to even think about it. I'm convinced that it's a crappy software issue with the latest macOS. Kinda just given up to be honest and accepted it. Which is ridiculous for such expensive machines.

Comment: This is an answer rather than a comment...
Open up a terminal and run this command:
    'sudo pmset -b hibernatemode 25'
Some time around the El Capitain/Sierra days Apple decided to change this default to 3 which meant that even when sleeping the memory was still powered so that it would be faster to resume. 
You can read more about what pmset does in a much longer reply here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126669/how-to-add-hibernate-mode-to-macbook-pro

Comment: Any more update on this? I have exactly the same issue for same year and model. Not quite sure what we can do? But for later model I tried, there is no such problem.

Comment: No updates - although i stopped paying attention to it a long time ago.

Answer (score 4):

If you open Activity Monitor there is an Energy tab that will display what is consuming the most energy. One of the columns is "Preventing Sleep", which will allow you to see if any apps are preventing your Mac from sleeping. It could be that it isn't sleeping when you think it is.

If you leave Activity Monitor open for a while it will gather data and you can look through and see what the biggest culprits are for energy usage. You could have a program that hangs and uses more power than it's supposed to.

Comment: Happy new year! So I did as you suggested.  Nothing was open preventing sleep.  20hrs this time on sleep and down to 78%.  This can't be right!

Comment: 22% loss on sleep over 20hrs is incredibly high, unless your keeping your laptop under extreme temperatures. At this point I would recommend taking it in to an Apple servicer and seeing what they say. I suspect the battery is faulty and will need to be replaced.

Comment: So - turning off bluetooth entirely seems to make this better.  48hrs and with opening the lid twice to check, I was down to 80%ish.  Still don't know if that's expected behaviour or not, whether I should take in for replacement?

Comment: That still seems like a lot of drain to me. Typically I think I lose 2-4% over a 12 hour period, but I can't confirm with hard numbers. Can anyone else pitch in with what battery loss they get overnight?

Comment: After leaving my Macbook closed for 14 hours (not turned off), I have lost 0% battery. I still think either your computer isn't actually going to sleep like it's supposed to, or your battery isn't holding a charge like it should.

Comment: Ok, mine lost 2% overnight last night (which is much better) - I had bluetooth turned off.  Mine is the Touch Bar 13 w/ 16gb ram.

Comment: I have the latest July 2018 MBP 13" with TouchBar. Closed the lid on Friday night with 100% battery, didn't open the lid even once, checked on Sunday morning and I am down to 30%. That's 70% loss in just over 32 hours. Activity Monitor shows 'kernel task' waking up few 100 times and I have no idea how to go around this problem. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.