# Macbook Pro 15, 2017: Discharges in Sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

My Macbook Pro 15, 2017 loses full charge (from 100% to 0%) during a 9 hr SLEEP duration.

Running this:

```
pmset -g
```

Throws the following result:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    259200
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         15
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by apsd)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
```

So far I have tried the following:

1. Reinstalled MacOS
2. Replaced Battery + Top cover + Keyboard + Trackpad, as a part of the Apple quality program.

Nothing has worked. Using the laptop is a pain. I can't leave it in sleep mode overnight, always requires shutting down.

Log:

```
2021-07-07 10:47:36.690749+0530  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2021-07-07 10:47:36.690752+0530  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2021-07-07 10:47:41.098745+0530  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

**Wake reason: EC.DarkPME** runs all night, non-stop!

Appreciate any help/fixes.

Comment: Sleep still uses power to maintain the RAM contents. You need to use hibernation instead. To enable hybernation [you need to use the pmset command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126669/how-to-add-hibernate-mode-to-macbook-pro) to set `hibernatemode` to 25. Right now it's 3 - the RAM contents are saved to disk but the machine is still powered

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It does not use 100% of a new battery in 9 hours just to maintain RAM contents, this is misinformation.

Comment: @Ant is it? Are you at the poster's home or office, looking at their machine? With a thermometer (temperature affects batteries)? Macs have problems with their batteries, just like all laptops. I think if I google I'll even find a battery recall in the news. I've encountered far worse battery problems: In our dev shop, out of 50 Macbook Pro 2018 we had *several* instances where the battery got so swollen the lid couldn't close. We ended up keeping our Macs open which caused the next problem - failing butterfly keyboards due to dirt

Comment: @Ant as for a Macbook eating up lots of battery during sleep, mine does. Definitely not 100%, but it's not trivial either. A "new" battery may have been sitting at some warehouse for years, especially if it's for an old model. Batteries degrade even when not used which is why they have expiration dates. We don't know the expiration date of the new battery

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your response. I have used this laptop in sleep mode for days without more than 1-2% drop in battery charge. 100% drain in sleep mode overnight is unheard of. The reason I got the battery replaced was complete drain, even after replacing it follows the same trend.

Comment: @MandeepSingh check the `sleep  1 (sleep prevented by apsd)` line. That's the `Apple Push Notification` service. Looks like the service is keeping the machine awake. Did you make any notification changes before the problem started?

Comment: @MandeepSingh try `pmset -g logs` to see what wakes up the machine. [In this case](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8613582) the culprit was the `Find My Mac` setting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos pasted log in first post.

Comment: I have a similar machine with a very bad battery and although it doesn't use 1-2% during the night in sleep, it is always below 10%. Draining the battery down 0% is definitely not normal.

Comment: Tried this. Turned off WiFi, Bluetooth, Handover. Charged to 100% left lid open, Apple logo -> Sleep. Lost 5% in 1 hr. Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance) triggers every 30 seconds.

Comment: `Host`, `HID` do you have a USB device attached? Faulty port perhaps? Googling for `AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver` returns a *lot* of hits but unfortunately no definite answers. Quite a few dismissive answers though - my favorite was "MacBook isn't an iPhone". I'm just guessing here, but could `lidwake` have something to do with the issue? Macbooks don't have mechanical switches (that I know of), so maybe, just maybe, this is the OS checking a USB-attached lid sensor?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No USB devices attached. All the USB-C ports work when I connect to them, which should mean they are working fine. The screen was damaged and that was also replaced recently, so lidwake should also be ok. The only thing not replaced on my MBP is the Logic board. Everything else was replaced a week back.

Comment: Once again attempted a clean install of Big Sur. Erased the disk and reinstalled. Default settings and no apps installed. Still the same issue, wondering if it is a hardware problem. Anyone with a similar experience?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Apple engineers think it's the **logic part** that doesn't work properly.

There are some solutions editing plist file on the internet, but even if I turn off SIP, I didn't manage to make any change to the system plist file. Try taking it to Genius Bar and change the logic part.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).